# error: ‘struct RakNet::SocketDescriptor’ has no member named ‘socketFamily’|

Tags: c++, irrlicht, raknet

when i run my client code i get this error i using code::blocks and im linux system in the tutorial that i follow the code working without any errors my includes files in the project

```
#include "MessageIdentifiers.h"
#include "RakPeerInterface.h"
#include "RakNetStatistics.h"
#include "RakNetTypes.h"
#include "NetworkIDObject.h"
#include "NetworkIDManager.h"
#include "BitStream.h"
#include "RakSleep.h"
#include "WindowsIncludes.h"
#include "PacketLogger.h"
```

> ```
> the error: ‘struct RakNet::SocketDescriptor’ has no member named‘socketFamily’| in the line 39 in the client.cpp file
> ```

client.h file

```
    #include "raknetincludes.h"
    #include "irrlicht.h"


    class Client
    {
      private:
          int numSockets;
          int numIPs;
          int maxPlayers;
          unsigned char packetIdentifier;

          RakNet::SocketDescriptor socketDescriptor;
          RakNet::NetworkIDManager networkIDManager;
          RakNet::NetworkID playerNetworkID;
          RakNet::MessageID typeID;
          RakNet::Packet *p;

          unsigned char GetPacketIdentifier(RakNet::Packet*p);

      public:
        Client(int=8);
        void CreateClientInterface();
        void SetIP();
        void ClientStartup();
        void ShutDownClient();
        void ReceivePackets();

        RakNet::RakPeerInterface *client;

        std::string serverPort;
        std::string clientPort;
        std::string serverIP;

    };
```

client.cpp file

```
#include "client.h"
#include "customnetworkenums.h"
#include "raknetincludes.h"
#define DEBUG_BUILD

Client::Client(int maxPlay)
{

    maxPlayers = maxPlay;

    serverPort = "6001";


}
void Client::CreateClientInterface()
{

    client = RakNet::RakPeerInterface::GetInstance();
    if(!client){


    }
    RakNet::SystemAddress clientID = RakNet::UNASSIGNED_SYSTEM_ADDRESS;


}

void    Client::SetIP()
{
    serverIP= "127.0.0.1";
    clientPort = "6000";
}

void Client::ClientStartup()
{
  socketDescriptor = RakNet::SocketDescriptor(atoi(clientPort.c_str()),0);


  socketDescriptor.socketFamily = AF_INET;
  client->Startup(8,&socketDescriptor,1);
  client->SetOccasiona1Ping(true);
  RakNet::ConnectionAttemptResult car = client->Connect(serverIP.c_str(),atoi(serverPort.c_str()),"yoyo", (int)strlen("yoyo"));
  RakAssert(car==RakNet::CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_STARTED);


}

void Client::ReceivePackets() {

     for(p=client->Receive();p; client->DeallocatePacket(p), p=client->Receive())
     {
        packetIdentifier = GetPacketIdentifier(p);
        //RakNet::BitStream bsIn(p->data,p->length,false);
        //RakNet::BitStream bsOut;

        switch (packetIdentifier){

          case ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
               printf("ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION from %s\n", p->systemAddress.ToString(true));
               break;

          case ID_ALREADY_CONNECTED:
               printf("ID_ALREADY_CONNECTED\n");
               break;

          case ID_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
               break;

          case ID_INCOMPATIBLE_PROTOCOL_VERSION:
               printf("ID_INCOMPATIBLE_PROTOCOL_VERSION\n");
               break;

          case ID_REMOTE_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
               printf("ID_REMOTE_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION\n");
               break;

          case ID_REMOTE_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
               printf("ID_REMOTE_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION\n");
               break;

          case ID_CONNECTION_BANNED:
               printf("you are banned from this server\n");

               break;
          case ID_CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAILED:
               printf("connection attempt field \n");
               break;

          case ID_CONNECTION_LOST:
              printf("ID_CONNECTION_LOST from %s\n",p->systemAddress.ToString(true));
              break;

          case ID_NO_FREE_INCOMING_CONNECTIONS:
               printf("sorry, the server is full \n");
               break;
          case ID_INVALID_PASSWORD:
               printf("Acces Denied : inccorrect client password\n");
               break;
          case ID_CONNECTION_REQUEST_ACCEPTED:
               printf("your connection has been accepted to %s with gud %s\n",p->systemAddress.ToString(true), p->guid.ToString());
               break;
          case ID_SPAMN_PLAYER:


              break;


          default:

            break;










     }



}

unsigned char Client::GetPacketIdentifier(RakNet::Packet*p)
{
    if(p==0)
        return 255;

    if((unsigned char)p->data[0] == ID_TIMESTAMP)
    {
          RakAssert(p->length > sizeof  (RakNet::MessageID)+sizeof(RakNet::Time));
          return (unsigned char) p->data[sizeof(RakNet::MessageID)+ sizeof(RakNet::Time)];

      } else
          return (unsigned char) p->data[0];




}


void Client::ShutDownClient()
 {

    client->Shutdown(300);
    RakNet::RakPeerInterface::DestroyInstance(client);

 }
```

Comment: It is pretty obvious what the problem is, just read your error message.  socketDescriptor.socketFamily = AF_INET;  

If you can't figure it out based off of that error message, then you shoudln't be coding network games yet.